# Font resize max size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a font resizer for my website. I need to set a maximum size for the resize.

The resizer works but not sure why my maximum value is not working?

```
// Reset Font Size
var targetContainers = $('.one-third, .two-thirds');
var originalFontSize = $(targetContainers).css('font-size');

// Increase Font Size
$(".resize-larger").click(function() {
    var currentFontSize = $(targetContainers).css('font-size');
    var maxSize = $('18');

    if (currentFontSize < maxSize) {

        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.2;
        $(targetContainers).css('font-size', newFontSize);
        return false;

    }

});​
```

Comment: it seems like since you have two elements that you are selecting that `currentFontSize` would be an array so in your later code you are just using the variable itself instead of getting a certain value in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Because `$('18');` is not a number. Don't go overboard with jQuery:

```
var maxSize = 18;
```

Comment: I tried that but when I use 18 the entire resizer does not work.

Comment: var maxSize = '18'; 

This works just be sure to include the ''

Comment: @infatti actually is supposed to be `var maxSize = '18pt';` because the "pt" adds the css type for the font size

Answer (score 2):

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D5kUS/)

I've modified your original idea and accounted for the fact the when getting the CSS `font-size` using jQuery the unit (e.g., `px`), is dealt with correctly. The font-size will be "capped" to the maximum value you have specified in the `maxSize` variable.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="resize-larger">[+] Increase Font Size</div>   <br /><br />

<p class="one-third">This is a test</p> <br /><br />

<p class="two-thirds">This is a test</p> <br /><br />

<br /><br /><br />

<div id="results">Current font-size: </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.resize-larger {
    width: 175px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


p {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Reset Font Size
var targetContainers = $('.one-third, .two-thirds');

// Increase Font Size
$(".resize-larger").click(function() {

    var currentFontSize = parseFloat($(targetContainers).css('font-size'), 10);

    var maxSize = 18;

    // This 'if' is 'true' when var maxsize (a number) is larger than var currentFontsize (also a number).
    if (currentFontSize < maxSize) {

        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.2;

        // Once the calculated newFontSize value is obtained, it will be capped to maxSize if it's larger.
        if (newFontSize > maxSize) {
            newFontSize = maxSize;
        }

        // This will show the current font-size in the results div.
        $('#results').html('Current font-size: ' + newFontSize + 'px');

        // Apply the newFontSize value, adding in unit of 'px' to the current value.
        $(targetContainers).css('font-size', newFontSize + 'px');
        return false;

    }

});


// On page load, the results div will be populated with the current font size.
$('#results').html('Current font-size: ' + $(targetContainers).css('font-size'));
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pruGc/16/

```
// Reset Font Size
var targetContainers = ['.one-third', '.two-thirds'];

// Increase Font Size
$(".resize-larger").click(function() {
    var currentFontSize;
    var maxSize = 40;

    for (var i = 0; i < targetContainers.length; i++) {
        currentFontSize = parseInt($(targetContainers[i]).css('font-size'), 10);

        var newFontSize = currentFontSize * 1.2;
        if (newFontSize < maxSize) {
            $(targetContainers[i]).css('font-size', newFontSize);
        } else {
            $(targetContainers[i]).css('font-size', maxSize);
        }
    }
});​
```

what i did was instead of having a array of selected elements, i put their class names in an array and then just use that in a `for` loop to get every one in the array and then set each one to the desired size.

also what this does is enable you to have a different `font-size` for each element and make each one separately larger.

for some reason idk why but even if the css property is set in the for of 'pt' it translates it to 'px' so saying the max is 18 (im assuming you mean, like in Microsoft Word, font size 18) would be wrong.

Comment: @arttronics ok i just fixed the jsfiddle again with the correct if statement. so try the log output again.. it should work

Comment: @arttronics thanks :D got rid of the `=`. and using the array allows for the individual elements to have a different `font-size` and update each one separately as can be seen in the fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/pruGc/16/). idk if it does that or not doing it the other way.. it might actually

Comment: **+1** Great answer, I like the array feature! Most likely the OP is looking to have `.one-third` and `.two-third` increase in `font-size` but cap them once `.one-third` reaches the `maxSize`... but that's just a requirement guess for both our answers.

Comment: @arttronics yes thanks **+1** for your answer as well as it works too :)

Comment: I think the OP is looking for your answer with an additional return included. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pruGc/17/). What do you think?

Comment: mhmm actually it does not work if the first and second `div`s are flipped in size.. i wish i could un **+1** your comment :/

Comment: The OP has class names indicating `.one-third` and `.two-thirds`, so that means there are preset font-sizes to those class names with relative font-sizes. I don't think that's a problem. I guess `one-third` can be *contents* and `two-thirds` can be *header* for example.

Comment: @arttronics either way the `return` doesnt do what you think it should do.

Comment: The `return` preserves the layout. Once `maxSize` of ***any*** class name in the array is detected by the `else` statement, it triggers an exit of the function. I see it working in Firefox with div's switched around too. *Where is the bug at*?